# How to marshal calls to specific threads in C# using TPL

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

I have a situation where I have a polling thread for a TCPClient (is that the best plan for a discrete TCP device?) which aggregates messages and occasionally responds to those messages by firing off events.  The event producer really doesn't care much if the thread is blocked for a long time, but the consumer's design is such that I'd prefer to have it invoke the handlers on a single worker thread that I've got for handling a state machine.

The question then is this.  How should I best manage the creation, configuration (thread name, is background, etc.) lifetime, and marshaling of calls for these threads using the Task library?  I'm somewhat familiar with doing this explicitly using the Thread type, but when at all possible my company prefers to do what we can just through the use of Task.

Edit: I believe what I need here will be based around a SynchronizationContext on the consumer's type that ensures that tasks are schedules on a single thread tied to that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question then is this. How should I best manage the creation, configuration (thread name, is background, etc.) lifetime, and marshaling of calls for these threads using the Task library?

This sounds like a perfect use case for `BlockingCollection<T>`.  This class is designed specifically for producer/consumer scenarios, and allows you to have any threads add to the collection (which acts like a thread safe queue), and one (or more) thread or task call `blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable()` to "consume" the items.

Comment: This seems a reasonable idea, but would require a pretty nasty restructuring I think, is there something more lightweight I could use a bit more discretely?

Comment: @Firoso Maybe - but without knowing a lot more about your architecture, it's difficult to know.  `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is what BC uses under the hood - you may be able to maintain your own queue to process there.  There is no way to directly "marshal" to a thread unless it has a synchronization context, though...

Comment: BC? Did I miss something here?  Anyhow I assumed I'd need to have sync contexts coming into play.

Comment: @Firoso `BlockingCollection<T>` can be used to have multiple producer threads add items to "consume" without using a sync context, since it's 100% thread safe.

Comment: I will do some digging and either attempt to implement this or simply edit my question to more completely specify my requirements, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) where you setup an [`ActionBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) that you push messages into from your TCP thread and then TPL DataFlow will take care of the rest by scaling out the processing of the actions as much your hardware can handle. You can also control exactly how much processing of the actions happen by configuring the `ActionBlock<T>` with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Since processing sometimes can't keep up with the flow of incoming data, you might want to consider "linking" a [`BufferBlock<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29) in front of the `ActionBlock<T>` to ensure that the TCP processing thread doesn't get too far ahead of what you can actually process. This would have the same effect as using `BlockingCollection<T>` with a bounded capacity.

Finally, note that I'm linking to .NET 4.5 documentation because it's easiest, but TPL DataFlow is available for .NET 4.0 [via a separate download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14782). Unfortunately they never made a NuGet package out of it.

Comment: I'm actually using these often, so it's your opinion that I can simply enforce handling by setting MaxDegreeofParallelism to 1?

Comment: You could. Perhaps I need to understand your dispatching algorithm more. The pattern you describe seems counter-intuitive to the typical producer/consumer pattern in that you actually care about which consumer threads you're dispatch to. Classes like ActionBlock<T> and BlockingCollection<T> are more about fanning the work out to as many possible workers as possible while the producer remains agnostic about how many/who do the work. So maybe if you explain more why you need to dispatch to a particular thread we could offer better solutions than these.

Comment: It has to do with the fact that the protocol its self goes into await states, and while that thread is suspended, I wanted it to only process the events then.

Comment: Well if you use something like the TPL dataflow approach there won't be any threads being used at all unless there is data pushed into the block. Since they are thread pool threads, they would be available to process any other requests in the process at the time. Whether that be for some other block or something totally unrelated to your specific workload.